# Como eu centralizo a caixa de pesquisa no Magento?

Tags: xml, magento, cms

Galera, boa noite.
Estou desenvolvendo uma loja virtual com o CMS Magento na versão 1.9.3.8 e queria saber como faço pra centralizar o conteúdo que marquei na imagem.
Ficarei grato se me ajudarem com isso, pois estou há semanas tentando e nenhum resultado! rsrs[image: centralizar todo o conteúdo]

Answer (score 0):

essa alteração deverá ser feita via CSS, diretamente no Tema que está sendo utilizado.
No elemento "div" aonde se encontra o input de busca, deverá estar com "display:inline-block" e largura "width" definida, já o elemento superior, aonde está div está alocada deverá estar com as propriedades "width:100%;text-align:center"

Comment: Obrigado, já consegui! Foi só tirar o position:absolute do #header-search e depois ir alinhando.